# Menu bar and images/buttons don´t align properly

Tags: ios, swift

I´m having trouble with NSLayoutConstraints. I wanted to create a custom menu bar right underneath the header with some images(or buttons) for the navigation but I have no idea why the images do not properly align in the middle and I guess the menu bar does not align underneath the header.. I tried to fix it with changing some values but I´m clueless at this point.

```
    private func setUpMenuBar() {
    view.addSubview(menuBar)

    let viewWidth = view.viewWidth
    menuBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    menuBar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
    view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    menuBar.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
    view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    menuBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive 
    = true
    menuBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 
   viewWidth).isActive = true
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your menuBar is currently the same width as your view so this is why your buttons are evenly spaced across the view. Try making your menuBar half of the view width so that your buttons are closer together (you can experiment here):

```
menuBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewWidth / 2).isActive = true
```

If you also want a bit of space between the bar, try adding a topConstraint (you can experiment with changing the 30):

```
menuBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
```